# Download image from browser via Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, images, google-chrome-extensions

I am thinking of creating a Chrome Extension that would allow you to download any image in the browser to a 3rd party app with the click of a button. I can inject the button into the page using a ["content-script"](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/). But what I am not sure of is if I can always grab the image from the browser cache or if I will need to go to the url where the image was retrieved.

The *problem* is that downloading the image via the url may require authentication (if the image were on FB or Twitter etc), and I don't think I can get those creds via the Chrome Extension.

So my question is - is the copy of the image shown in the browser something I can always retrieve or no? For example:

```
<img src="some-url"></img>
```

when the image represented by the tag is displayed in the browser, is there a way to retrieve it 100% of the time without credentials?